# questions about firebase and web hosting with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-hosting

I want to publish a website using firebase but I have the following questions:

1. For how long can I use firebase for free?
2. Can I add a custom domain name if I have one while publishing the website?
3. If I publish my website and it started getting more views, will I have to pay for firebase?

Comment: one more question will i be able to edit my website after hosting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please visit the [Firebase Pricing Site](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)
2. Yes you can use a custom domain name after deploying the website. There is an opportunity in the Firebase console "Add Custom Domain".
3. You will have to pay for the services when you exceed the free reads etc. in the free firebase plan. But you have to switch to the Blaze Plan first. When you didn't switch to the Blaze Plan, you will just get no more answers from the database etc. after exceeding the free plan.

Comment: thanks but i am not able to understand the pricing and as for the third one my website is a simple website with simple html css and javascript and i am a beginner to web dev so i am not able to understand if I will deploy my website will i be charged

Comment: You have 50.000 reads from your database per day free in the free plan. One read = one document received from the firestore. If you dont use the firestore this doesn't matter. If you just use firebase just to host your project, and it is a small website it is very unlikely that you will exceed the free 360 MB/day data transfer.

But even if you exceed it you wont't be charged before you explicitly switched to the blaze plan where you have to enter credit card information. If you exceeded and you didn't switch to blaze plan, the site just wont be reachable for this day anymore.

Comment: so if i have not aquired the blaze plan and the maximum limit is exceeded in any way the website will be not reachable for that day right? and what about the second day will my website remain closed or it will get good the next day? thanks in advance

Comment: According to the Firebase FAQs the Datatransfer is calculated monthly so you have 360mb / day in average which sums up to 10gb data transfer per Month. If you use over 10gb data transfer in a month your website will be disabled for the remaining month and will be online again to the beginning of the next month.

Comment: for what purpose is this 360 mb data?

Comment: What do you mean? You can learn more about the hosting usage here https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/usage-quotas-pricing

Comment: it is showing this :-  Data transfer (GB/month) — The amount of data transferred to end users from our CDN. Every Hosting site is automatically backed by our global CDN for free.                     as i said i am a complete beginner i am not able to understand what is data transfer

Comment: The data transfer means the amount of data transferred from the server to the client (browser). So if you host a simple html website, the amount of data is the size of your html file (maybe 800bytes). if you provide more complex websites with huge files and lots of stuff to process the data which has to be transferred is larger.

Comment: so what is the difference between hosting storage and data transfer hosting storage because on the site hosting storage seems like that also.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Spark plan, you have `360 MB/day` bandwidth i.e. once your usage exceeds for the day your website will not be served. This involves all the images, html and css files that you deploy to Firebase hosting. On the other hand, storage is used to store your websites files (you can also request to store previous versions of your website and rollback anytime.)

Comment: ok i am just confused about difference between the both